# what is definition of generic function?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, mapping-class-group

what is definition of **generic function** in following [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjBqNSai_30AhWpRPEDHeGeDGYQFnoECAgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpi.math.cornell.edu%2F%7Ehatcher%2FPapers%2FMCGpresentation.pdf&usg=AOvVaw113eSaaQ0fOElNR-jKX5eQ) ? i need a reference for definition  generic function .

"A. Hatcher, W. Thurston, A presentation for the mapping class group of a closed orientable surface "

...let f be any **generic function** on M having $C_1, . . . , C_r$ as non-critical level curves....

Comment: I’m no expert, but it seems like they mean “**arbitrary** function”, as in “any function will do”

Comment: What they're saying is that most functions satisfying the condition will work: there might be a few which you need to avoid for some reason (critical locus does something weird, you want it to not vanish to too high an order on some submanifold to be prescribed later, etc) but an open dense set of the space of all functions under consideration will work.

Comment: In general, "generic" means "belonging to a set of full measure". Which set this refers to depends on context. A quick keyword search of the linked paper yields the following comment on page 223: "If *f* is generic, that is,
if all the critical points of *f* are nondegenerate with distinct critical values, ..."